# Custom Sinatra route

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

I'm looking to make a custom route for my Sinatra blog project which shows the user the last entered post in the database.

```
get "/most-recent-job" do
  Job.last
```

Can anyone help? I can't find info in my curriculum for such a request.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. Your question isn't asked well.

Answer (score 0):

The Sinatra [documentation on routes](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html) is pretty thorough. Assuming you're just trying to call a class method of Jobs::last, and that the method returns something stringifyable, then:

```
get '/most-recent-job' do
  Jobs.last
end
```

should get it done. If that's insufficient for your use case, you'll have to expand your question to include code and output showing what `Jobs.last` is supposed to return, whatever errors you're getting from the route currently, and what you think the route's output ought to look like if you're expecting a MIME type other than `text/plain`.

Comment: but will job.last work . i havnt set up that route manually is that something that is built in that i could just use?

Comment: or should i do something like this

Jobs::OrderBy('created_at', 'desc')

Comment: @hihello91 If you have not created a Jobs class or an instance of Jobs, then no: it will not work automagically out of the box. You have to create the logic that you’re trying to call if it’s not a built-in Ruby or Sinatra class.

Comment: i do have a job class setup but that isnt working. is there a way to write a route in sinatra that can show the last entry in the database. in my case the last job posted in the job blog database. I just want to get an idea of how to structure the route. sorry if im being unclear im a noob